# Subquery in CakePhp with InnerJoin

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to convert this query:

```sql
SELECT
    pdd.pedinte_id, pdd.data, pdd.situacao as Situacao, pdd.valor_total, pdd.qtd_etiquetas, 
    (
        SELECT count(pdi.envio_id)
        FROM pedinte_item pdi
        INNER JOIN envios env ON
            pdi.envio_id = env.envio_id
        WHERE
            pdi.pedinte_id = pdd.pedinte_id AND
            env.Situacao = 2
    ) AS TemErros
FROM pedinte pdd
left join user usr on
    usr.user_id = pdd.user_id
WHERE pdd.user_id IS NOT NULL AND pdd.pedinte_id IS NOT NULL;
```

to CakePhp:

```php
removed code, maybe very wrong.
```

Without success.

I have 4 tables:

- `pedinte` (`pdd`)
- `pedinte_item` (`pdi`)
- `envios` (`env`)
- `user` (`usr`)

`pedinte` > `pedinte_item` > `envios` (`count`)

Cant believe, harder to do the query builder than the mysql code.

Comment: Suggests bad database design. Subqueries are never good. Perhaps address that instead? 
Not sure I fully understand the query. Maybe add a field to store the aggregate? If you can't contort this to Cake, use raw SQL and mapper or a MySQL view?

Comment: I did it, raw mysql and recreated the paginate system.

Comment: Condolenses.  Frameworks try to make things easier.  But instead, they simply force you to learn _two_ languages and deal with the incompleteness of each.

Answer (score 0):

(This does not address the CakePHP question, but too long for a Comment)

(Subqueries are not always "bad".)

These indexes may help performance:

```
usr:  INDEX(user_id)
pdi:  INDEX(pedinte_id, envio_id)
env:  INDEX(Situacao, envio_id)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.